# Cannot call value of non-function type 'AnyObject!?" Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to fix this error but no see solution.
In other codes that works! No sense!

Support Class ScrolledString: print string in a view that is scrolled.

```
class ScrolledString: NSView{
var text: NSString = "";

init(frame frameRect: NSRect, string:NSString){
    self.text = string
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    self.text = ""
    super.init(coder:coder)
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40.0)
    let attrs : [String: AnyObject] = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.whiteColor()
    ]
    text.drawInRect(self.frame, withAttributes: attrs)
}
```

Than in mainView I'm trying to add a ScrollView

```
let scrollStringContainer = NSScrollView(frame: NSRect(x: myRect.width*4/9, y: 0, width: myRect.width*8/9, height: myRect.height))
let view = NSView()
view.addSubview(ScrolledString(frame: scrollStringContainer.frame, string: self.name))
scrollStringContainer.documentView(view)
```

Last line return error "*Cannot call value of nun-function type 'AnyObject'*". I'm simply trying to add a view to scrollView

Comment: At least you have to initialize a *physical* `NSView` with its designated initializer.

Answer (score 0):

> `unowned(unsafe) var documentView: AnyObject?`

`documentView` is an optional property of type `AnyObject`, so you can't call it like a function. I'm not clear if you mean to be using `contentView`, as in:

```
scrollStringContainer.contentView.addSubview(view)
```